# iOS Core Animation Queue

Tags: ios, animation, core-animation, queue

I have multiple CALayers. And I want to be able to animate them sequentally using CAAnimation (and it's subclasses) animations. I wrote methods that prepare animations and add it to layer, one animation per method. Now, how I could create animaiton queue? CAAnimationGroup couldn't be used because animations are applied to different CALayers. NSOperationQueue isn't working because all UI actions should be done on main thread. The only solution I found is to create NSArray of NSInvocation objects, but this solution doesn't seem to work in iOS 5...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a common delegate for all your animations. As each animation ends, it will notify its delegate (`-animationDidStop:finished:`), which can then fire up the next one.

Answer (score 1):

> CAAnimationGroup couldn't be used because animations are applied to different CALayers

Actually, that's not true. A single CAAnimationGroup *can* animate different CALayers. You add the animation to the superlayer and refer to properties of the different layers using the key path notation `"sublayers.[layername].[property]"`.